# Stop when data ends

Tags: excel, outlook

The code goes down the names in Column A and creates an email for each unique name, placing the corresponding names in column E as a list.  It goes on to the next unique name in A until done.

Sample data.
[image: Sample Data]

When it gets to the end, or a blank in the name column 1, it creates an error.
[image: Error]

Line where it shows the error in break mode.
[image: Code Line Stop]

When it gets to the bottom of the list at Shirt,Gray, it tries to go to the next line but since it is blank, it errors out.

```vb
Sub TEST3()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim strname As String
    Dim strname1 As String
    Dim strname2 As String
    Dim strEmp As String
    Dim previousName As String
    Dim nextName As String

    Dim emailWS As Worksheet
    Dim nameCol As Double
    Dim nameCol2 As Double
    Dim empCol As Double
    Dim lastCol As Double
    Dim lastRow As Double
    Dim startRow As Double
    Dim startCol As Double
    Dim r As Double
    
    Dim empList As String
    
    sigstring = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\work.htm"
                              
    If Dir(sigstring) <> "" Then
        signature = GetBoiler(sigstring)
    Else
        signature = ""
    End If

    empList = ""
    previousName = ""
    nextName = ""

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    Set emailWS = ActiveSheet
    startRow = 2
    startCol = 1
    nameCol = 3
    nameCol2 = 1
    empCol = 6
   
    lastRow = emailWS.Cells(emailWS.Rows.Count, nameCol).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = emailWS.Cells(1, emailWS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For r = startRow To lastRow
        strname = (emailWS.Cells(r, nameCol2))
        strname1 = Trim(Split(emailWS.Cells(r, nameCol2), ",")(1))
        
        strEmp = emailWS.Cells(r, empCol)

        If emailWS.Cells(r + 1, nameCol2) <> "" Then
            nextName = (emailWS.Cells(r + 1, nameCol2))
        Else
            nextName = "Exit"
        End If

        If strname <> previousName Then
            previousName = strname
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            
            With OutMail
                .To = emailWS.Cells(r, 2).Value
                .Subject = "Low Balance "
                empList = strEmp & "<br>"
                strbody = "<Font Face=calibri>Dear " & strname1 & ", <br><br> As of the last week, the below have a low balance. "
            End With

        Else
            If InStr(empList, strEmp) = 0 Then
                empList = empList & strEmp & "<br>"
            Else
            End If

            If strname <> nextName Then
                OutMail.HTMLBody = strbody & "<B>" & empList & "</B>" & "<br>" & signature
                OutMail.Display
            Else
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub

Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
End Function
```

Comment: It looks like your starting row is 2 when it should be 1 as you do not have headers.

Comment: Thank you, I have adjusted for this now, but it still gives the error.  Do you know how to get it to stop without an error at the end?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @Kavorka, following up.  Do you have something I could mark as an answer?  Thanks!!

Comment: You can check for the comma before splitting `strname`: e.g. `If InStr(strname, ",") = 0 Then exit For`

Comment: It sounds like what I suggested did not fix your issue, If @Eugene Astafiev's suggestion worked, you should mark his as the answer. Or give an Up button to Ike

Comment: hi @Kavorka, thank you.  I did try that option and the error did go away...however, it ends up just putting the system in a loop back to the first row.  I did try other if, then, based on your statement above and it does work, but keeps looping back to the first row.  Let me know if I should be doing something differently, thank you!

Comment: With the sample data provided, what is your expected email suppose to look like?

Comment: Are you expecting 10 separate emails to come out?

Comment: Hi @Kavorka, the email just has a greeting, says that the following people have a low balance, and then it lists all the people under the email recipient.  It works to do that now, except when it hits the bottom, as there is no more names, so the strname1 throws the error, looking for the comma to do the split.  It does this at the first row too, if I include a header.  So i need it to know to skip or stop at a blank, or something with no comma in the cell.

Comment: I duplicated your data in a worksheet and I did not get any errors. It ran and spit out 1 email

Comment: It should create one email per person on the first column, with all their people in column E listed.  So rows 1 and 2 would have one person each, then the next person would have ten people listed in the email, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your last comment, here is the updated code. I moved the last `end if` to be above the code that shows the email.

Please note you may have to re adjust the `startrow` and `empcol` as I changed them to work with the data I duplicated

```
Option Explicit
Sub TEST3()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Dim strbody As String
Dim strname As String
Dim strname1 As String
Dim strname2 As String
Dim strEmp As String
Dim previousName As String
Dim nextName As String

Dim emailWS As Worksheet
Dim nameCol As Double
Dim nameCol2 As Double
Dim empCol As Double
Dim lastCol As Double
Dim lastRow As Double
Dim startRow As Double
Dim startCol As Double
Dim r As Double

Dim sigstring As String
Dim Signature As String

Dim empList As String

'Get work signature
sigstring = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\work.htm"
                          
If Dir(sigstring) <> "" Then
    Signature = GetBoiler(sigstring)
Else
    Signature = ""
End If

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set emailWS = ActiveSheet

startRow = 1
startCol = 1
nameCol = 3
nameCol2 = 1
empCol = 5

lastRow = emailWS.Cells(emailWS.Rows.Count, nameCol).End(xlUp).Row

lastCol = emailWS.Cells(1, emailWS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For r = startRow To lastRow
    
    strname = (emailWS.Cells(r, nameCol2))
    strname1 = Trim(Split(emailWS.Cells(r, nameCol2), ",")(1))
    
    strEmp = emailWS.Cells(r, empCol)

    If emailWS.Cells(r + 1, nameCol2) <> "" Then
      
       nextName = (emailWS.Cells(r + 1, nameCol2))
    Else
       
       nextName = "Exit"
    End If

    If strname <> previousName Then
        
        previousName = strname
       
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        
        With OutMail
         
           .To = emailWS.Cells(r, 2).Value
           .Subject = "Low Balance "
            empList = strEmp & "<br>"
            
            strbody = "<Font Face=calibri>Dear " & strname1 & ", <br><br> As of the last week, the below have a low balance. "

        End With
    Else

        If InStr(empList, strEmp) = 0 Then
            
            empList = empList & strEmp & "<br>"
            
        End If

    End If
    
    If strname <> nextName Then
        
        OutMail.HTMLBody = strbody & "<B>" & empList & "</B>" & "<br>" & Signature
        OutMail.Display
    End If
    
Next r

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: hi @kavorka, thank you but same problem.  When the code gets to the end of the list, it throws the same error at the same line, calling out that same line of code that I highlighted.  The code needs to know to stop or adjust for when the next line is blank or does not have a comma.

Comment: Did you readjust the `Startrow?` I wrote the macro based on the data above. When I duplicated it and ran the macro, it performed like we discussed

Comment: Yes, I adjusted it...i have to, or it just stops completely because the very first row is a header and has no name/comma in it.  I put it to the 2nd row and it ran as intended but only until the last row, as it does not know to stop at a blank or non-comma (name) cell.  So in the above, when it gets to Shirt, Gray, it should stop because there is nothing below it (last row), but it does not, it keeps going to that next line. Did you look at the debugger when yours ended?  I had to look there to see the error (it did not pop up in front of the emails).

Comment: On my machine the macro works as intended. I get no errors and it doesn't go past the last row other than the `If` statement that assigns `nextName = "Exit"`   I am not sure why yours is going past the Last row

Answer (score 3):

The problematic line of code contains multiple property or method calls:

```
strname1 = Trim(Split(emailWS.Cells(r, nameCol2), ",")(1))
```

I'd suggest breaking the chain of property and method calls by declaring each property or method calls on a separate line of code.

For example, the first operation could be a value from the worksheet:

```
result = emailWS.Cells(r, nameCol2)
```

The second operation could be a split:

```
splitResults = Split(result, ",")
```

The third operation could be getting an item from the array and the fourth could be a trim.

So, you could see intermediate results under the debugger attached and fix the code easily.

Comment: Hi @Eugene Astafiev, thank you...I have been trying for hours to do what you said, but am ending up nowhere.  I tried to add in your code but am not sure where...I then tried to set strname1=splitresults but keep getting a type mismatch error.  I tried to dim it as a string, but no joy.  Sorry, I am am novice and am failing to follow your instructions.  Is there something else I need to do?  Thank you.

Comment: hi @eugene Astafiev, let me know if you have any other suggestions, thank you.